# CSS - targeting pseudo element when a HTML element contains another specific class

Tags: html, css

I have some buttons in my app that have use many different modifier classes, here is an example

```
<button class="btn btn--compact btn--edit">
  Button Text
</button>
```

I have the class `btn-edit` that adds a background image using the `:before` pseudo element like so (notice that this is SCSS)

```
.btn {
    &--edit:before {
    background: url("ic_create_18x18.svg") no-repeat;
    background-position: -3px 3px;
    background-size: contain;
    content: '';
    filter: $filterWhite;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

it works well but should the button element also contain the `btn--compact` class like in my example above I wish to use a different size icon and some other CSS rules. So I need to overwrite the class / make my selector more targeted. Some thing like this I thought

```
.btn--compact.btn--edit:before {
    background: url("ic_create_16x16.svg") no-repeat;
    background-position: -1px 2px;
        height: 14px
}
```

Hmmm... my selector doesn't work, so I changed it to this

```
.btn--compact .btn--edit:before {}
```

This also doesn't work!?! How do I target the :before pseudo element for the `btn--edit` class on an html tag / element that also has / contains the class `btn--compact`?

Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: (ignore this I'm wrong) Without trying anything, my first guess is this is a specificity issue. `.btn.btn--edit::before` and `.btn--compact.btn--edit::before` have the same specificity, so whichever is defined last in your file will take precedence.

Comment: @Auroratide `.btn { &--edit:before` would compile to `.btn--edit:before` so it can't be a specificity issue

Comment: @Pete Good point, thanks for the catch.

Comment: @MikeSav can you make a [mcve] as your code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/sd2cfo43/1

Comment: `Hmmm... my selector doesn't work, so I changed it to this` what do you mean exactly ? i just tested it and it works.

Comment: I have the problem... kinda. If I added the code at the end of my SCSS file the code worked, so it was an issue of precedence... sorry to waste your time.